# Why does Google Search Engine reject my title tag's change?

Tags: google-search, title

I made a simple webpage and giving it the the **title tag** "**Boat – Pundaquit**" and I have submitted it to Google bot by Google Webmaster Tools.

Then I decided to **change the title** to "**Anawangin trip**" of the same page and I submited my webpage again in the same way to Google bot.

The result was that the new title of my webpage coexisted with the old title of the same webpage in SERPs for maybe 2 days.

After that **the new title was rejected** and if I enter site:pundaquitboat.michaelspages.com/  I can see that Google has my old copy of my webpage with old title in its database.

---

This problem doesn't occur in Bing when I can enjoy high position of "**Anawangin trip**" phrase. (In Bing I haven't submitted the old version of title.)

Comment: Also bear in mind that the _title_ that appears in Google SERPs is a dynamic entity. Google will change the title that appears to make it more relevant to the users search query - which is not necessarily the title of the page.

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for GoogleBot to index the page again, the lower the rank of the page, the longer it takes for GoogleBot index it again.

Like you can see (at least at google.com), the page was last seen on Nov 2.

So you must wait, and like w3d said, even when google indexes the page again, it is up to google to decide which title to display on the SERP.

Comment: Strange, that title was used in the past. Google has a new copy of my webpage now with a new title and it uses the old title.

Comment: Different result gives the search "site:pundaquitboat.michaelspages.com" and "info:pundaquitboat.michaelspages.com"
There r different copied of my webpage if i choose to see the copy or I use copy thumbnail (>> - hover on). Hv U got any links to explain all those abnormalities?

Comment: When I search for site:... the title is now "Anawangin trip"

Comment: Not on my PC. :) Interesting :)